# Project hotel reservation in Python with OOP and multithreading

Tags: python, object-oriented, multithreading, python-3.x

I have to create a project in Python 3 for a university exam. The project involves the use of object-oriented programming and the use of multithreading. My project is based on the simulation of booking a hotel room. I then created a `Stay` class with its instance variables and its methods. For multithreading I tried to implement a competing book, inserting global variables as the number of available rooms by type.

rooms.txt:

> Single
>
> Double
>
> Triple
>
> Matrimonial

price_rooms.txt:

> Single Yes 46.0
>
> Single No 40.0
>
> Double No 70.5
>
> Double Yes 76.5
>
> Triple No 90.0
>
> Triple Yes 96.0
>
> Matrimonial No 65.0
>
> Matrimonial Yes 71.0

I have doubts about the use of object-oriented programming and especially on multithreading. Can you help me regarding a correct use of this?

```
from datetime import datetime, date
from threading import Thread
import threading

class Stay:
    '''Classe per la prenotazione di un Stay.'''
    def __init__(self, room_type= '', from_date= '00-00-0000', days= 0, breakfast= '', price= 0.0):
        self._room_type= room_type
        self._from_date= from_date
        self._days= days
        self._breakfast= breakfast
        self._price= price
    def __str__(self):
        return '\nTipology of room: %s\nDate: %s\nNumbers of days: %s\nTotal price: %d\n' % (self._room_type, self._from_date, self._days, self._price)
    def set_room_type (self, room_type):
        while True:
            try:
                try:                
                    rooms= open ('rooms.txt', 'r')
                except IOError:
                    print ('Files for reading the kinds of rooms corrupt or not found\n')
                lista= [] 
                for riga in rooms:                  
                    room = riga.strip()
                    lista.append(room) 
                rooms.close()
                print ('\nSelect the type of room that interests:')
                room=input('')
                if room in lista:
                    room_type= room 
                    self._room_type= room_type
                    break
                elif room.islower(): 
                    raise ValueError
                else:
                    print('Enter a type of room available\n')           
            except ValueError:
                print('Enter the room with only the first letter capitalized\n')


    def get_room_type (self):
        return self._room_type

    def set_from_date (self, from_date):
        date_today = date.today()
        print('Insert the date of arrival:')
        while True:
            data = select_date()
            if data >= date_today:          
                from_date = data
                self._from_date= from_date
                break
            else:
                print('The date is not available')

    def get_from_date (self):
        return self._from_date

    def set_days(self, days):
        while True:
            try:
                print ('How many days you want to stop in our structure?\n')
                ndays=int(input(''))
                if ndays >= 1:
                    days=ndays
                    self._days= days
                    break
                else:
                     ndays == 0
                     print ('Enter a valid number of nights')

            except ValueError:
                print ('Enter a valid character')

    def get_days (self):
        return self._days

    def set_breakfast(self, first_breakfast):
        while True:
            try:
                print ('If you like our breakfast you type Yes, No otherwise')
                first_breakfast= input ('')
                if first_breakfast== 'Si':
                    breakfast= first_breakfast
                    self._breakfast= breakfast
                    break
                elif first_breakfast== 'No':
                    breakfast= first_breakfast
                    self._breakfast= breakfast
                    break
                elif first_breakfast.islower(): 
                    raise ValueError
                else:
                     first_breakfast != 'Yes' or 'No'
                     print('Enter an answer either Yes or No\n')            
            except ValueError:
                print('Enter the answer with only the first letter capitalized\n')

    def get_breakfast(self):
        return self._breakfast

    def set_price(self, price):
        try:
            cal_price= open ('price_rooms.txt', 'r') 
        except IOError:
            print ('Files for searching in prices corrupt or not found')
        for tipo in cal_price:
            riga= tipo.strip() #il metodo strip elimina gli spaziatori da una stringa
            lista= riga.split() #il metodo split spezza una stringa in singole parole
            if lista[0] == self._room_type and lista[1] == self._breakfast: 
                price = float(lista [2])*self._days
                self._price= price
                break
        cal_price.close()

def select_date():
    date_today = date.today() 
    anno = date_today.year 
    while True:
        try:
            print('Enter the day:')
            day = int(input(''))
            print('Enter the mounth:')
            month = int(input(''))
            while True:
                try:
                    print("Enter the year:")
                    year = int(input(''))
                    if anno == year: 
                        break
                    else:
                        if year < anno:
                            print('Enter the correct year')
                        elif year > anno:
                            print("You can not select a year other than the current one")
                except ValueError:
                    print('Invalid character')
            data = date(year, month, day)  
            break
        except ValueError:
            print("Invalid date . Enter the date correctly.")
    return data

def prenotazione (sema, op):
    sema.acquire() 
    op.set_room_type('room_type')
    op.set_from_date('from_date')
    op.set_days('days')
    op.set_breakfast('breakfast')
    op.set_price('price')
    print(op)
    global Single, Double, Triple, Matrimonial
    if op._room_type == 'Single' and Single > 0:
        Single = Single -1
    elif op._room_type == 'Double' and Double > 0:
        Double = Double -1
    elif op._room_type == 'Triple' and Triple > 0:
        Triple = Triple -1
    elif op._room_type == 'Matrimonial' and Matrimonial > 0:
        Matrimonial = Matrimonial -1
    else:
        print ('We are sorry , the type of room selected by you is not available , try to select another type')

    sema.release() 

print("Welcome to the reservation service rooms of our structure\nThe types of rooms available are the following:\n")

try:
    roomsdisp = open('rooms.txt','r')
except IOError:
    print ('Files for reading rooms corrupt or not found')
lista = []
for riga in roomsdisp:
    rooms = riga.strip() 
    lista.append(rooms) 
    print (rooms)
roomsdisp.close()   

Single= 1 
Double= 2
Triple= 1
Matrimonial= 1
reservation= Stay () 
sema = threading.Semaphore (1)
t1 = Thread(target = prenotazione, args = (sema, reservation,)) 
reservation2 = Stay()
t2 = Thread(target = prenotazione, args = (sema, reservation2,))
reservation3 = Stay()
t3 = Thread(target =prenotazione, args = (sema,reservation3,))

t1.start()
t2.start()
t3.start()
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Answer (score 4):

#### `==` instead of `=` "bug"

I saw this line in your code:

```
ndays == 0
```

In Python assignment is done with a singe `=`, using double `==` you are asking Python if the objects are equal **and discarding the result of such comparison**, there is no crash / unexpected behaviour here because `ndays=int(input(''))` overwrites `ndays` shortly thereafter anyway (so setting it to 0 would have been useless too).

I suggest removing such a weird "do nothing" line from your code to avoid confusing the readers (and yourself of the future).

#### Critical UI flaw

You asked for `yes` but checked for `Si` (italian word meaning `yes`).

The user will be unable to proceed in this branch because of this flaw:

```
            print ('If you like our breakfast you type Yes, No otherwise')
            first_breakfast= input ('')
            if first_breakfast== 'Si':
```

Comment: I thank you for the answer. I will correct mistakes , can you tell me how to improve the reservation through multithreading ?

Comment: @Peter I am sorry but I cannot help you on multithreading, try asking a follow-up question more focused on that  issue.